# How to blur the underlying background image within the area of a modal window with transparency?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, modal-dialog

I've added modal window with transparency into a web site, and I'd like to apply such as Gaussian blur to the window background, just like Windows vista's aero glass effect. Is it possible for me to do that? and, how?

Thanks!
William

Comment: Try to use fancybox or thickbox to display your modal window. If u wont like Make it possible using css

Comment: agreed, i highly recommend fancybox :)

Comment: You probably can't blur the whole page via CSS or JS (except IE with it's filter), only images via canvas. Though, background image with "glass" pattern plus some shadows and opacity might be fine too. Also, there are always SVG with filters, but I'm into it.

Comment: But I can't find the way to blur only portion of the background image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a dynamic width/height flash widget which loads the image, blur filters it, and set the containing element fairly precisely in a z-index layer, above the modal underlay and below the modal content. Alternatively, http://plugins.jquery.com/project/blurimage, or http://www.nihilogic.dk/labs/imagefx/ also looks promising.

EDIT: In response to your 'partial image blurring comment'

Using that Flash widget and positioning, yeah - off the top of my head you might try a double-layered swf at full size, the bottom layer contains the image asset, as does the layer above it, this top layer would be fully blurred - and the top layer is also masked. Size the mask to the panel you have open (set up some onresize handlers etc if needed). If your panels are draggable, track the position of your HTML panel versus the position of the panel-sized second layer in Flash, ultimately moving around a mask to reveal only the blurred region of what looks like a single image.

Also note that you'd need `ExternalInterface` for this to be efficient, so min. Flash player 8, which beats the sparse browser implementations listed at [http://www.nihilogic.dk/labs/imagefx/](http://www.nihilogic.dk/labs/imagefx/.).

Another thing springs to mind, which might only need two `<div>` elements, both containing the same image as above, layered on top of each other as above, and you'd manipulate [CSS clip properties](http://www.w3schools.com/CSS/pr_pos_clip.asp) in relation to the size/position of your opaque panel. If it were a [YUI Panel](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/container/index.html), you could use the modal underlay layer as your 'bottom layer' in my Flash example above, and the Panel itself is wrapped so you could possibly use CSS clip and JS blur in there, maybe even `background-position:fixed` and JS blur could help... I'd be keen to see some of your attempts if you manage to try any - wish I had some spare time!

Comment: is it possible to blur only a portion of an background image?

Comment: Ok, I can qualify the above here with no Flash, and no Javascript to add the effect - though obviously Javascript is used to illustrate using a YUI Panel example: http://codefinger.co.nz/public/blurpanel/imagepartblur.html  -  I think it obviates a problem revolving around the visibility of content inside the panel - so you need two images, or one image which is duplicated and treated (maybe colour reduction or tinting) before being set as the panel's fixed background. If your situation is predictable enough you could set text to be the rgb opposite of the blurred background with Javascript.

Comment: And final comment, you could also process your images on the server first, creating your blurred duplicate and setting that as your panel's fixed background.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look

1. **[Windows Aero](http://www.soyos.net/Windows_7_UI_and_Windows_Aero_for_Websites.html)**
2. **[Aero Lightbox](http://www.soyos.net/tl_files/demos/Windows-7-UI-and-Windows-Aero-for-Websites/lightbox.html)**

Comment: Hey that's pretty cool, there's no blur or enlargement effect, but still very cool. You could skin a YUI Panel easily (use those graphics or do something with CSS3 and border radius + opacity), and leverage document boundary detection and other stuff.